# Making partial from crud view

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, partials

I am making a Wikipedia clone to learn ruby on rails. In my app I have collaboration and wiki models with their own controllers and views. I would like to make a partial of the `collaboration/new.html.erb` view and put it into the `wiki/new.html.erb`. Is this possible? If so how would it be as simple as labeling the collaboration `view _new.html.erb`?

Comment: Could you show us your code please buddy

Answer (score 0):

To refactor part of a view into a partial, extract the code you want to use and put it into a new partial under collaboration/_new.html.erb. Then to display this partial in a different view (such as the 'wiki' view), you would use the render function - making sure to specify the correct file path.

So in app/views/wiki/new.html.erb, add:

```
<%= render "collaboration/_new.html.erb %>
```